# Are there any benefits to changing my Zebra QLn220 device.languages setting from "hybrid_xml_zpl" to "zpl"?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Running "! U1 getvar "allcv"" in the Zebra Setup Utilities app to see what my Zebra QLn220 printer's settings are, I see (among a googleplex of other things):

```
device.languages : hybrid_xml_zpl , Choices: zpl,line_print,hybrid_xml_zpl
```

AFAIK, the code I'm sending to the printer via my app is pure ZPL, not hybrid XML + ZPL.

The code works ([usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942071/why-would-a-zebra-qln220-printer-ignore-the-first-couple-of-commands-sent-to-it)), so would there be any benefit to changing this value via the Zebra Setup Utilities app like so:

```
! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"
```

? Or am I just as well (or better) off to stick with the hybrid setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two settings are the same on that model if printer with the new architecture. The options are different for legacy reasons